# Trying to select a specific node with Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to select the text from the name attribute of the anchor element of the last `Comment` div in the `Comments` div (i.e. `comment_3037`) How can I select it?

Here's my html:

```
<div id="Comments">
    <div class="Comment"><!-- last "Comment" element in the div -->
        <a name="comment_3037"></a>
        <a href=""><img src=""></a>
        <div>
            <div class="Stats">Some info goes here</div>
            <div class="Body">Comment goes here.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is contradictory. You are trying to select the "text" from the "name attribute" of the anchor element - Does not make sense. I have no idea what you are trying to select from that. Can you rephrase please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Corrected Version**
(dojo.query always returns a nodelist)

This would look something like that:

```
var nodelist = dojo.query('#Comments > .Comment:last-child > a[name]);'
var value = dojo.attr(nodelist.at(0), 'name');
```

Explanation: `#Comments > .Comment` selects all nodes with class `Comment` inside the node with id `Comments`. `:lastChild` reduces this selection to the last child. `> a[name]` selects all immidiate children of type `a` with the attribute `name`. 
The second line just gets the value from the name attribute of the node.

You should get the correct element with that, but I haven't tested it.

Have a look at the dojo reference, there are tons of useful functions.
(I don't work at dojo, I just really like it ;) )

**Info**

http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/query

**EDIT**

To make sure that you get only the node you want (if you add another link with a name attr), you could add a class "thisisthelinkiwant" (or similar ;) ) to the appropiate link and updating the query to `'Comments .thisisthelinkiwant:last-child'`.

You might consider reading about css selectors, as they are quite important with this function.

Comment: thanks a lot! I couldn't get your example to work, but this is how I got it to work: var nameValue = dojo.query('#Comments .Comment:last-child > a[name]').attr('name');

Comment: Ok, this is interesting, because dojo.query() should return a list of nodes, not a single node... 
I might have a look at it again...